# Как центрировать View в LaynearLayout?

Tags: android-studio

Подскажите плз. как центрировать view в LaynearLayout c высотой "match parent" ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dice_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/dice_1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/roll_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/roll" />

</LinearLayout>
```

C этими параметрами view все равно отображаются вверху девайса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Может попробовать заменить у обоих `View` атрибут `android:layout_gravity` с `center_horizontal` на `center_horizontal|center_vertical`?